# Is it reliable to use oauth and rest framework in main web application?

Tags: django, rest, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I just started designing the new web application , in my old design i used sessions, web page rendered in back end,  now we thought to design using REST and oauth , normally i found that oauth and REST and using to integrate with third party services/application, so my question is can i do it in my main web front end in building in angular, and api services in rest and oauth? , is it reliable ?

Answer (score 0):

To integrate OAuth2, you may for example use `django-oauth-toolkit` with `djangorestframework`. The [authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) section in the DRF documentation has more detail.

Should I understand your question correctly, integrating with the "main" application is entirely possible, through URL-routing. See the corresponding sections in [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/) and [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/). With this approach, any api can go under, for example `www.app.com/api`, to separate from the main-application.

While entirely suitable for small to medium projects, for larger projects we found this approach difficult to maintain, mostly for dependencies and build times.